# Objects with variable fields in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

In rethinkdb, I'd like to create or modify objects with fields based on a string variable. But rethinkdb does not make a difference between `{key: 42}` and `{"key": 42}`, `key` will always be interpreted as a string literal.

As an example,

```
r.expr(['a', 'b']).map(function(key) {
  return {key: 42}
})
```

returns

```
[{"key":42},{"key":42}]
```

but I want

```
[{"a":42},{"b":42}]
```

---

The following query does that through manually building a string that represents the object in JSON and then parsing it, but it is quite error-prone and generally does not seem to be the right way to do it.

```
r.expr(['a', 'b']).map(function(key) {
  return r.json(r.expr('{"').add(key).add('": 42}'))
})
```

So, is there a good way to prevent rethinkdb from interpreting `key` as `"key"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `coerceTo`

```
r.expr(['a', 'b']).map(function(key) {
  return r.expr([[key, 42]]).coerceTo("OBJECT")
}).run(conn, callback)
```

The next version (1.12 -- coming this week?) introduced a new term `r.object` that removes the need for `coerceTo`.